# "No persister for: X.Domain.Person" Nhibernate Error

Tags: nhibernate

in My nhibernate.cfg.xml file I have

```
<mapping assembly="X.Domain" />
```

Which would usually works - Inside My X.Domain I have my Fluent Mappings. in which I have tests to verify all the mappings are set up correctly. Not sure if this is because I am using Fluent in my Domain Layer and nhiberante.cfg.xml in my MVC project.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

The `<mapping/>` element is part of NH core; it only recognizes hbm.xml files built as embedded resources, not fluent mappings.